# Testing performance of different code

Tags: java, android, benchmarking

Usually when I create something I have a number of different ideas on how to do it. Anytime I'm not sure which is better, rather than posting here each time, I'd like to test things myself. What methods can I use to test speed/performance/memory usage etc in Android?

Answer (score 0):

While I personally have little experience with them, [Performance Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Measure) offered by the Android Documentation gives mention to two potentially useful programs for checking benchmarks.

Upon a cursory glance, it seems [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) is useful for testing individual methods as well as broad scopes of an application.

Based on the documentation, creating a trace, retrieving it, and processing it can be done as follows:

First, find the locations where you want to test performance.  Here's a quick sample:

```
public void doSomething() {
    //maybe a long process that needs optimizing
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // set up stuff

   Debug.startMethodTracing("myfilename");
   doSomething();
   Debug.stopMethodTracing();
}
```

Second, retrieve the file from your Android device (note, you need a write-permission to create this file, so be sure to add that to your manifest).  This can be done using the Android Debug Bridge (located in `<Android SDK Home>/platform-tools`).  Open a command shell and run the following command

```
<Android SDK home>/platform-tools/adb pull /sdcard/myfilename.trace <Desired Location>
```

Lastly, you can process the output using `Traceview` with another command call.  `Traceview` is located in the `<Android SDK Home>/tools` directory, so the call would look like this:

```
<Android SDK Home>/tools/traceview <Desired Location>/myfilename
```

Note that depending on your operating system, you may need to switch forward slashes with back slashes.  This is a rough outline of the process outlined in the documentation (cited above), so I would recommend reading that before trying to implement this.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll take a read through that link, from a glance it looks like what I'm after, but I'll do some research first.